# Multiple annotations found at this line: End tag (</script>) not closed properly, expected >

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have written the below html code with the embedded javascript function disableReturnDate() within the script tags. But on the close tag  is  giving an error

****Error****

> ```
> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>   - End tag (</script>) not closed properly, expected >.
>   - Unknown tag (script function addReturnDate() { if (document.getElementById('RoundTrip').checked) 
>    { document.write("Select Return Date:"); document.write("<script>DateInput('returndate',true,'DD-MON-YYYY');"); 
>    document.write("<input type=\"button\" onClick=\"alert(this.form.returndate.value)\" value=\"Show date value 
>    passed\">"); } } </script> ).
>   - End tag of element <script>
> ```

****Code****

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Enter Date-Time, Arrival and Departure Location</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calendarDateInput.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function disableReturnDate() {
    this.form1.returndate.disabled=true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="disableReturnDate()">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="retrievePossibleRoutes.jsp">
Select Travel Date:  
<script>DateInput('traveldate',true,'DD-MON-YYYY');</script> 
<input type="button" onClick="alert(this.form.traveldate.value)" value="Show date value passed">
<br>
Select Return Date:  
<script>DateInput('returndate',true,'DD-MON-YYYY');</script> 
<input type="button" onClick="alert(this.form.returndate.value)" value="Show date value passed">
<input type="radio" name="journeyType" id="OneWay" onClick="disableReturnDate()" checked>One Way<br>
<input type="radio" name="journeyType" id="RoundTrip" onClick="enableReturnDate()">Round Trip<br> 
<br>
Select Departure Location:
<select name="comboDep">
<option></option>
<option></option>
</select>
<input type="submit"/>
<br>
Select Arrival Location:
<select name="comboArrv">
<option></option>
<option></option>
</select>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what's wrong. The code being shown in the error was written before but I have removed that now and it still shows in the error message. Look forward to replies

P.S. The link to the calendarDateInput.js is http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex7/jasoncalendar.htm

Comment: this may be a stupid question I'm going to ask, but you don't have `document.write` in `calendarDateInput.js` anywhere, do you?

Comment: That is a separate javascript that I have added as part of date input in the form of calendar. I am using that script and it is not shown in the current code

Comment: there are some script tags that I have added to add the DateInput function from the calendarDateInput.js

Comment: @Mr Lister, pls see the link to the calendarDateInput.js that I am using. It is meant to add a calendar input element to the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can verify HTML by using the W3C validator: http://validator.w3.org/check

Two errors of significance show up.  Put

```
<!doctype html>
```

at the start of the HTML (you can specify more info in the `doctype` tag, so look into this a bit more), and add make sure that all  tags have the `type` attribute set:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: actually I removed the first line                                  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> while pasting the code. Regarding the <script> tags without type="text/javascript", I am using a javascript code that generates html date input using Calendar. I added the types for those scripts as well, but still getting the same error.

Comment: @iND The `DOCTYPE` you mention doesn't require the `type` attribute in the `script` tag (although other DOCTYPEs do).

Comment: @MrLister, that may be, but W3C still throws an error for not having the `type` attribute when using `doctype` as I mentioned.  **@somnathchakrabarti**, it seems like you have an error somewhere in code not listed then.  You may have to post the other javascript to get an answer.

Comment: It looks like there is no `returndate` element in `disableReturnDate()`.  Not sure why you are expecting some element named `returndate` at all, as I don't think it is being added by the external JS and you haven't declared it in code.  However, I am not sure if this is your problem.

Comment: I have run the application with the DateInput and it basically adds a Calendar input element which is fine and working. The problem is </script> tag in the line 10 of my code. It is showing an error with the message "End tag not properly closed". I am struggling to find where I have not closed the tag

Comment: Please let me know the result if you change your function to: `function disableReturnDate() {try{form1.returndate.disabled=true;} catch (e) { alert(e); }}`  (adding a try-catch around the area where I am showing an error).

Comment: @iND: The problem disappeared when I closed and restarted Eclipse IDE. Thanks a lot, iND for your valuable comments and help!

Answer (score 2):

> The code being shown in the error was written before but I have removed that now and it still shows in the error message

That means that your browser has cached the old version. [Clear your cache](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache) and try again.

Comment: But if the old version is cached by browser, why am I getting the red underscore error in my Eclipse IDE where I am creating this web-app?